# Sum column until a criteria is matched in the adjacent column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a table looking like the following:

```
Col1 | Col2
-----+-----
   A | 12
   A | 4
   B | 5
   A | 16
   A | 8
   B | 91
   C | 6
   A | 55
-----+-----
   C | ???
```

What I want is if I type `C` (a text value) in the lower left cell, to display in the `???` marked cell the sum of the values of `Col2` that are above the last `C` (i.e. 12+4+5+16+8+91). In the same way if I type `B` in the same cell I want to have 12+4+5+16+8 as a result.

I tried with `SUMIFS` and `VLOOKUP` with no luck. How do you do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the following formula:

```
=SUM(B1:INDEX(B:B,MATCH(2,IF($A$10=A1:A8,1))-1))
```

Entered as an array formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

`IF($A$10=A1:A8,1)` returns an array of `1` and `false`. If the range is equal to C, then we get the array `{false,false,false,false,false,false,1,false}`, and `MATCH(2, {false,false,false,false,false,false,1,false})` returns `7`, which becomes `6` when 1 is taken off it.

Then index returns the cell B6, which is picked up by `SUM` to make the range `B1:B6`.

If `C` is changed to `A`, we get: `{1,1,false,1,1,false,false,1}`, which `MATCH` returns `8` and the `SUM` becomes `B1:B7`.

Answer (score 0):

Using a cell reference with text is a little different. You have to surround the reference with `&` to get Excel to use it.

The formula below is entered into `B9` and reads cell `A9` as the value to exclude. As you can see, you could just use `=SUMIFS(B1:B8,A1:A8,"<>C")` to get what you want, but it wouldn't read the value in cell `A9`. Below uses the text.

```
=SUMIFS(B1:B8,A1:A8,"<>"&A9&"")
```

[image]

Comment: Just reread the question and realized my answer doesn't account for stopping at the last occurrence of the letter. Nonetheless, maybe my answer will help someone else.